# isset($_POST['remember']) checkbox issue in PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, checkbox, isset

I need to test if a checkbox is checked. I've searched for the solution and found it, but it still don't work for me.

Here's my form :

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input id="remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="loginform">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and my PHP code :

```
if (isset($_POST["loginform"])) {
    if(isset($_POST['remember'])) {
        $month = time() + 2592000;
        debug_to_console($month); // function equivalent to console.log in JS
        setcookie('remember_me', $_POST['username'], $month);
    }
}
```

**EDIT , debug_to_console() function :**

```
function debug_to_console( $data ) {
    if ( is_array( $data ) )
        $output = "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . implode( ',', $data) . "' );</script>";
    else
        $output = "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $data . "' );</script>";
    echo $output;
}
```

**EDIT 2 (Whole PHP code) :**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_COOKIE['remember_me']))
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_COOKIE['remember_me'];

    $success = true;

    if (isset($_POST["loginform"])) {
        if(isset($_POST['remember'])) {
            $month = time() + 2592000;
            echo "<h1>Month: $month</h1>";
            setcookie('remember_me', $_POST['username'], $month);
        }

        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        // Form Validation
        if (!$email || !$password || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            $success = false;
        else
        {
            Db_connect($connection);

            $email = stripslashes($email);
            $password = stripslashes($password);
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $email);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $password);

            $query = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from users where email='$email'");
            $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

            if ($rows == 1) {

                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                $hashpass = $row['password'];

                if ( hash_equals($hashpass, crypt($password, $hashpass)) ) {
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['username'];
                    header("location: login.php");
                }
                else
                    $success = false;
            } else
                $success = false;

            mysqli_close($connection);
        }
    }

    function Db_connect(&$connection){
        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "project_web");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    function debug_to_console( $data ) {
        if ( is_array( $data ) )
            $output = "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . implode( ',', $data) . "' );</script>";
        else
            $output = "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $data . "' );</script>";
        echo $output;
    }
?>
```

When i submit my form with the checkbox checked, and i look at the console, it is empty, while it is supposed to display the value of $month. Which means $_POST['remember'] is not set while it is supposed to be set due to the form submit.

Can anyone help please ?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: what this debug_to_console?

Comment: it is a function equivalent to console.log() in javascript. It just shows the parameter given in the console.

Comment: It's not `$_POST["loginform"]` the issue. The issue is in `console.log()`. BTW, you **can't output** in console using php. In no way

Comment: I replace this function with echo, and your code work correctly

Comment: what do u mean by `equivalent to console.log()`, please add this function in question `debug_to_console`. also if you want to check the value of `$month` use `var_dump($month);` instead `debug_to_console($month); `

Comment: Why are you focusing in the debug_to_console function ?
Actually, it works just fine and it does exactly what she is meant to. The problem is this part : if(isset($_POST['remember']))

Comment: No. `if(isset($_POST['remember']))` works.

Comment: But .. then why it doesn't enter to my condition and execute the cookie creation script ?

Comment: See this [demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/azyb-9spm) > `$_POST['remember']` works. Try to put `echo 'Something';` inside your `if` condition: if you doesn't have output, the problem is before in the code.

Comment: post the code from start of script to `isset` condition

Comment: it works fine in your PhpFiddle, but still not in my code, i put the whole PHP code, see **Edit 2**

Comment: @fusion3k , I still found no solution, I would be grateful if you can help.

Comment: You don't see `<h1>Month: $month</h1>` or you don't see the console output?

Comment: in the new code i used `echo "<h1>Month: $month</h1>";` as you suggested, and i don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

$_POST['remember'] would be true or false .... remove value =1 ... you will get value ... true or false ... validate according to that ...

Comment: I tried that, didn't work either :/ Actually, it was one of the solutions i found, so i already tried it before...

Comment: This is irrelevant for the question and it doesn't change the code behavior in any way.

Comment: i guess action is missing probably that would be the case

Answer (score 1):

> Make an action attribute like

```
    <form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

> The php code

```
    if (isset($_POST)) {
     if(isset($_POST['remember'])) {
     $month = time() + 2592000;
     debug_to_console($month); // function equivalent to console.log in JS
     setcookie('remember_me', $_POST['username'], $month);
     }
    }
```